# radio button ID value

Tags: jquery

I have a radio group where I need to do some math calculations based on the value of the radio selected, but I also need a way to know my identity value for the SQL record it represents. Normally I would have that stored in the "value" attribute of the radio button.

What I tried to do here is have different ID's for the same class, and I am trying to figure out how to determine the ID assigned

```
<input type="radio" class="price" name="price" value="20.00" checked="true" id="1" />
<input type="radio" class="price" name="price" value="385.00" id="2" />
<input type="radio" class="price" name="price" value="504.00" id="3" />

$('.price').change(function() {
calculate();
});

function calculate () {
    var q = $('input#quantity').val();
    var p = $("input[name=price]:checked").val();
    var tot = ((q*p)+parseInt(s));
    $('input#total').val(tot);
};
```

So in the calculate() function, I get the value but how can I get the ID for the radio button checked? Maybe this is backwards and there is a better way to get my dollar value for the math calculation part and I am open to any suggestions.

TIA - Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the way you have your HTML right now, you could use this:

```
var id = $("input[name=price]:checked").attr('id');
```

**BUT!**

The `id` attribute is reserved for the DOM, and on top of that, it <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't start with a number. I might suggest using `jQuery.data()` instead. Simply add `data-` to the front of the `id` attribute you had:

```
<input type="radio" class="price" name="price" value="385.00" data-id="2" />
```

And then retrieve the `data-id` attribute using the following:

```
var id = $("input[name=price]:checked").data('id');
```

Comment: Your right. I felt like I was using it the wrong way and your suggestion here accomplished what I was trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elem.attr('id')`, but you should be careful with abusing the `id` attribute like that; in theory they need to be unique, and [must start with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

If you want to attach arbitrary data to an element, you can use [data attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#custom-data-attribute). For example:

```
<input type="radio" class="price" name="price" value="20.00" checked="true" data-id="1" />
```

Then you get the value out with:

```
elem.data('id')
```